# Info.plist key strings - defined in the SDK, or do I have to create them?

Tags: ios, api, key-value, nsbundle, info.plist

For example, does Apple provide `NSString * const kCFBundleDisplayName` somewhere? Or do I have to do it myself?

```
NSString * const kCFBundleDisplayName = @"CFBundleDisplayName";

@implementation NSBundle (Sugar)

+(NSString *)displayName {
   return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:kCFBundleDisplayName];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kCFBundleNameKey` is defined in the iOS SDK, and gets you the short name. The display name does not have an iOS SDK defined constant (you have to do it yourself).

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1544/_index.html

Comment: I see, thank you. What about others... `NSHumanReadableCopyright`, `CFBundleVersion`, etc? I take it that, if they exist, they will be scattered around in various frameworks, according to their prefix? Maybe I'll just stick with what I'm doing, defining them myself.

Comment: Not sure, but I know the keys for you app can be found in the file `InfoPlist.strings`